# Casting Down Data Contract Objects

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I've got an object on my client that derives from a class that is being sent over a WCF contract. I'm hitting problems de-serializing this as it appears to send the class over as it stands, and the deserialization on the server side determines what object to create and populate, and as the object only exists on the client it falls over.

I looked at the KnownType attribute and tinkering with the KnownType configuration section, but these all affect only the server (Recieving) side of the contract.

What i want to do is use my derived class and have only the base class information serialized and sent over the pipe, using WCF. Using just casting does not change the object type, and it is still serialized as is.

It seems to me the KnownType mechanism is somewhat backwards, is there any way to handle this from the client side?

Regards

Tristan

Comment: So you have a `Base` object with the `[DataContract]` attribute, and a `Derived` object inheriting from `Base`. Is it important that you know it as derived once it arrives on the server ?

Comment: Correct.

I've inherited on the client, and the server has no knowledge of the derived class. I want to send the base class over the the wire, rather than the derived class. Is there any way to serialize only the base type?